# Identify only human-readable files in linux

Tags: linux, filesystems

I have 8 files in the linux operating system and i want to know which one of them is only-human readable file .

```
-file00  -file01  -file02  -file03  -file04  -file05  -file06  -file07  -file08  -file09
```

how can i do this ?

Comment: Define human readable.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for files that match the `text/plain` MIME Type, then you could use `file --mime-type`, which will have a "*best guess*" at what the file is... pair that with `grep` and you might get a reasonable result.

```
# put the name of each file into the `files` variable
files=( * )

file --mime-type -- "${files[@]}" \
  | grep -E ': +text/plain$'
```

Note that `file` doesn't actually scan the entire file to make this "*best guess*" assessment, so you may get some false positives. Additionally, I'm not sure how it will deal with Unicode...

If you're after something else, then please revise your question with more detail on what you're after.

Comment: Note the names in question begin with `-f`. Use `./*` or [`--`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/108618).

Comment: @attie `file` properly identifies UTF8-encoded files (`UTF-8 Unicode text`)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thanks... I had actually assumed that was an artefact of incorrect formatting, oops.

Comment: @attie `file` assigns the UTF-8 file the same `text/plain` MIME type as a pure ASCII file.

Comment: @xenoid great, thanks! I was wondering if there was an `; encoding=utf-8` or anything appended